# Jquery lightbox click :not

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

I'm trying to get a :not click event with jquery.
Essentially I'm trying to build a lightbox. Works fine, but I would like it to close ONLY if the black space is clicked. If the image is clicked lightbox should not hide.

Please see the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nrUCc/7/
I have tried this: (line 42 in the js column)

```
 $('#lightbox').not('#lightbox img').click(function(e){
        $(this).css('display','none');
 })
```

..but still it triggers when I click on the image.

Any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the target element against `this`:

```
$('#lightbox').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) { 
        $(this).css('display','none');
    }
});
```

`e.target` is the element which triggered the `click` handler, `this` is the `#lightbox` element. So basically you're saying only trigger the `click` handler when `#lightbox` has been clicked. This will also prevent any other child elements of `#lightbox` from triggering the above `click` handler.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrUCc/12/)

---

An alternative would be to add another `click` handler to the `#lightbox > img` elements, and simply stop the click event from propagating and triggering the above:

```
$('#lightbox > img').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```